# Как вызвать BOOL из другого контроллера?

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Что мне написать во втором view, чтоб сработал в нем этот код, к примеру (сверку @import OneViewController - это я написал):

```
 + (CGFloat)iPhoneRetina4Height:(BOOL)landscape
{
if (landscape)
{
    return 320.0f;
}
else
{
    return 568.0f;
}
 }
```

(Спс, учусь пока, куча пробелов в знаниях.)

Comment: а разве автоматически все разрешения не отслеживаются?

Comment: Наверно, это как пример) просто у меня есть библиотека прописаных функций в viewControllere, хочу в остальных их просто вызывать, да вот не вызываются только!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#import "One.h" 
CGFloat tmp =  [One iPhoneRetina4Height:YES];
```

При этом + `(CGFloat)iPhoneRetina4Height:(BOOL)landscape` должно быть в обьявлено в `One.h`.